# Cabal not performing quickCheck test

Tags: unit-testing, haskell, cabal, quickcheck

I'm writing a cabal file to install a library written with Haskell. I want some tests (written with `quickCheck`) to be performed at installation.

The cabal file looks like :

```
...
build-type:          Simple
cabal-version:       >=1.8


Test-Suite my_tests
  Type:               exitcode-stdio-1.0
  Hs-Source-Dirs:     test
  Main-is:            Tests.hs

Library
  Hs-Source-Dirs:     src
  Exposed-modules:      HsMesher.Fonctions
                      , HsMesher.Types
                      , HsMesher.Algorithmes1D.Arcs
                      , HsMesher.Algorithmes1D.Segments

  Build-depends:       base ==4.5.*
```

and the `Test.hs` file to perform tests is :

```
import Test.QuickCheck
import HsMesher.Algorithmes1D.Segments
import HsMesher.Algorithmes1D.Arcs
import HsMesher.Types

...

main = do
  putStrLn "My tests"
  quickCheck prop_test1
  quickCheck prop_test2
```

when I run `runhaskell test/Tests.hs` test routine is performed correctly.

But when I type `cabal configure --enable-tests && cabal build && cabal test`, tests are not performed and I have the following message :

**cabal: No test suites enabled. Did you remember to configure with
'--enable-tests'?**

However library is installed correctly with `cabal install` and archived correctly with `cabal sdist`.

Do you have an idea of what is wrong ?
Is there something I didn't understand in the integration of quickCheck with Cabal ?

I'm using cabal v1.14.0, ghc v7.4.1

Comment: `cabal biuld` does work? I'd expect that the test needs `build-depends: base, yourlibrary` (at least).

Comment: I don't see any reason why this would produce that error. Can you include the full error message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It 's important to **not forget dependency** when calling test suite as far as cabal doesn't complain explicitly when you forget them.

```
Test-Suite my_tests
  Type:               exitcode-stdio-1.0
  Hs-Source-Dirs:     test
  Main-is:            Tests.hs
  Build-depends:      base ==4.5.* , HsMesher, QuickCheck
```